# Cannot clone repository ("Operation not permitted: <workspace_folder>/<project_name>/.hg/requires")

Tags: mercurial

Sorry in advance for my bad english...
I'm trying to clone an hg repository using Eclipse on Ubuntu.
I always have the following error message which is exactly the same when I perform a "hg clone" command :

```
"Operation not permitted: <workspace_folder>/<project_name>/.hg/requires"
```

Here is the /.hg content :

```
ls -al .hg/
total 40K
drwxrwxr-x 4 www-data web 4.0K Apr 18 09:33 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data svn 4.0K Mar  5 17:52 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data web   57 Mar  5 17:48 00changelog.i
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data web 4.0K Apr 18 09:33 cache
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data web   40 Mar  5 17:51 dirstate
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data web   40 Apr 18 21:45 requires
drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data web 4.0K Apr 18 09:33 store
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nico     web    0 Apr 18 09:33 undo.bookmarks
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nico     web    7 Apr 18 09:33 undo.branch
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nico     web   38 Apr 18 09:33 undo.desc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nico     web   40 Apr 18 09:33 undo.dirstate
```

And here is the /.hg/requires file content :

```
revlogv1
store
fncache
dotencode
```

Here is the output of the hg clone command :

```
running ssh nico@www.there.com "hg -R /var/dev/projects/my_hg_project serve --stdio"
sending hello command
sending between command
nico@www.there.com's password:
remote: 145
remote: capabilities: lookup changegroupsubset branchmap pushkey known getbundle unbundlehash batch stream unbundle=HG10GZ,HG10BZ,HG10UN httpheader=1024
remote: 1
destination directory: my_hg_project
abandon : Operation not permitted : /media/data/workspaces/my_workspace/my_hg_project/.hg/requires
```

I tried many things such as chmod and chown... I'm not a linux expert so I googled my error message but there is not many results.
Has anyone an idea about this?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

You're right to be thinking file permissions because that's the root cause, but I'm a little confused.  Are you showing up the file permissions on the server, but seeing that message on the your workstation?  Where exactly are you trying to clone from and to?  Are you cloning over http or ssh?  What user are you running the clone command as?

Comment: Thanks for your response! :) 
I was showing the files permissions on the server because I think the problem is here. 
I see the error message in my workstation when I attempt to clone the project. 
I try to clone a project from a server in my enterprise in order to work at home. 
I try to clone the project over ssh with this URL (it works when I clone at work and I can connect to this server via ssh) : ssh://nico@www.xxxxx.com/<hg_repositories_path>/<my_hg_project> 
So I try to clone with the user "nico" (me). I also try to clone with the root user.

Comment: If <hg_repositories_path> is an absolute location (not relative to your home directory you need a double slash before it like: ssh://nico@www.there.com//absolute/path/to/my_hg_project

Comment: are you sure you're able to ssh into that work server from home at all?  If you can't ssh in you can't clone over ssh.  Also please provide the **full** output of the `hg clone --debug URL` command.

Comment: You are right. My URL is like you say : ssh://nico@www.there.com//var/dev/projects/my_hg_project.
I'm sure I am able to ssh into that work server from home (I succeed again today). Here is the output of the command :

Comment: running ssh nico@www.there.com "hg -R /var/dev/projects/my_hg_project serve --stdio" #
sending hello command #
sending between command #
nico@www.there.com's password: #
remote: 145 #
remote: capabilities: lookup changegroupsubset branchmap pushkey known getbundle unbundlehash batch stream unbundle=HG10GZ,HG10BZ,HG10UN httpheader=1024 #
remote: 1 #
destination directory: my_hg_project #
abandon : Operation not permitted : /media/data/workspaces/my_workspace/my_hg_project/.hg/requires

Comment: Sorry, I can't add linebreaks so I have symbolized them by a "#" char.

Comment: Usually one edits the question to add additional information.

Comment: Can you make everything on the server owned by nico and group-owned by web?  `chown -R nico:web /var/dev/projects/my_hg_project` on the server should do it.  Then `find /var/dev/projects/my_hg_project -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod g+s` to make sure they stay that way.  Then they're group-opened by the web user for http access and owned by you for ssh access.

Comment: Thanks. I have executed your commands but I have the same problem. The output of the hg clone --debug is exactly the same. It also didn't work when I tried to clone with the server root user.

Comment: You might want to join #mercurial on freenode IRC and work this out with someone interactively.  SO isn't the right place for a long debugging session, and your unwillingness to put your actual output in the question only makes it harder.